# PhpStorm when searching, start in default scope

Tags: phpstorm

I have made myself a scope in PhpStorm 2019.3 and excluded some directories from the project, awesome!

When I start searching with <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd> (`Find in Path`) it always goes to find something into a specific directory (duh). Every time I search for something I use this hotkey and have to manually click on 'Scope' and then select the scope I want to search in.

I couldn't find a hotkey like 'find in scope' or anything close to that. I was wondering if there's like a hidden hotkey for this or any workaround? I really like searching for stuff so hope its possible since its really time consuming clicking 2 times to enable the scope before searching.

Comment: Find in Path is a bit context dependant: when you invoking it when focus is in Project View panel (especially on a folder) then it will use that folder as a base for a search. But when you invoke it when focus is in Editor, it will use the previously used scope/place. That's how it works for me (checking in 2019.3.4 x64 on Windows 10) -- I do not need to manually select the same scope on next invocation.

Comment: If it works differently for you, maybe you can record small screencast that will demonstrate how it works? It may show some omitted nuances etc.